# No Such Method Error for simple Java file (return type int)

Tags: java, int, return, program-entry-point, nosuchmethoderror

I have the following short program, compiles fine (written and compiled on a a Linux box).  If I use public static void main(String[] args) and get rid of the return 4; statement it compiles and runs fine.  With the return type I receive the following error (at runtime not when building):

I do have to return an int for the purpose of this application, I cannot use a void type.

-java HelloWorld

Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

The file name is HelloWorld.java (HelloWorld.class after the build).

What's causing this issue? Thank you!

I've tried changes such as a colon after the second to last }, changing to int main, public int main, static int main, writing main and string with an uppercase first letter, nothing has seemed to resolve.  I'm using the String[] args as I will be picking up parameters on the final application.

```
public class HelloWorld 
{
public static int main(String[] args) 
{
System.out.println("Hello, World");
return 4;
}
}
```

Comment: I do have to return a value for the purpose of this application and how it will be used. need to return an int.

Comment: Try this  `http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_syntax.htm`

Comment: Java `main` method MUST be `public static void main(String[] args)`, Java's main method doesn't return a value (like C), instead, you can use `System.exit(int)` to set the exit value

Answer (score 3):

Java is not `C` and the entry-point must have a `void` return type.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

to return a non-zero value to the calling process, you can use [`System.exit(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) like

```
System.exit(4);
```

Note that (per the Javadoc) *the argument serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination.*

Answer (score 0):

Try with public static **void** main, and not return value

Comment: His version will work just fine (it'll compile and run). That's not the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

In the Java language, when you execute a class with the Java interpreter, the runtime system starts by calling the class's main() method. The signature of the main() method cannot be changed, in order to be executed must be `public`, `static` not returning anything and accept a String arrys `String[]`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){}
```

Hope it helps,

Jose Luis

Answer (score 0):

`main()` is invoked by the runtime at the class level, hence it has to `public` and `static`. Also, in C++, the return value of `main()` is typically used to indicate the exit status of the program. In Java, there are other ways to do this and `main()` does not need to return a value. Hence it needs to also be `void`

Answer (score 0):

Usually in languages like C and C++ `main` is allowed to return an `int` to indicate exit codes, e.g. `0` for successful exit, any other number for an error. This is so an external program may interpret the results from the run.

To achieve similar functionality in Java you'll want to use [System.exit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) allowing for a return value. Something like:

`public static void main(String[] args) {
    int toReturn = 1;
    System.exit(toReturn);
}`

Just so you know, most standards ask you to adhere to the idea that anything other than zero is an error.